# Traduction de l'expression religieuse "Rapture"?

Tags: religion

En anglais, cela désigne l'élévation au ciel des croyants lors de l'Apocalypse. Quelle est la traduction française la plus courante?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L'expression utilisée communément pour l'élévation au ciel des croyants lors de l'Apocalypse est **l'Enlèvement de l'Église**, ou plus simplement **l'enlèvement**.

On retrouve des définitions partout, par exemple [ici](https://wol.jw.org/fr/wol/d/r30/lp-f/1101989259) :

> ***Définition*** : Croyance selon laquelle les fidèles chrétiens seront brusquement enlevés de la terre et emportés hors de ce monde dans leur corps de chair pour rejoindre le Seigneur “dans les airs”

La Bible n'y fait jamais ouvertement référence ([c'est d'ailleurs un sujet de débat au sein des croyants](https://www.mondedemain.org/revues/2014/juillet-aout/croyez-vous-a-l-enlevement)), mais **tous les écrits qui en parlent utilisent cette dénomination**.

Par exemple, [ici](https://www.bible-ouverte.ch/messages/etudes/177-enlevement-de-leglise.html), [ici](https://wol.jw.org/fr/wol/d/r30/lp-f/1101989259) ou même sur [Wikipédia](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiKsMzJ4sLWAhWDHxoKHS7RC1oQFghPMAc&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffr.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FEnl%25C3%25A8vement_de_l%2527%25C3%2589glise&usg=AFQjCNE0u5orGxnEPxGcBL7ZM7cpUaSmQw), on peut retrouver ce terme.

Answer (score 1):

1 Thes. 4:17:

Nous serons tous ensemble **enlevés** avec eux sur des nuées (trad. Louis Segond)

simul **rapiemur** cum illis in nubibus (Vulgate)